# Rails Rspec transaction fixture not working with multithread

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, rspec

I'm trying to reproduce the racing condition problem with RSpec.
I spent a day to searching around and so far I have:

#### *in my helper:*

```
def create_concurrent_calls(object, method, params=[])
processes = 2.times.map do |i|
      ForkBreak::Process.new do |breakpoints|
        original_method = object.method(method)
            object.stub(method) do |*args|
            value = original_method.call(*args)
            breakpoints << method
            value
        end
        object.send(method, *params)
      end
    end
    processes.each{|process| process.run_until(method).wait}
    processes.each{|process| process.finish.wait}
end
```

#### *in my spec:*

```
describe "My code issuer" do
    let!(:category) { create(:category) }
    let!(:code) { category.codes.create(code: 'code1') }
    self.use_transactional_fixtures = false 
    it "returns different codes for each" do
     expect(PregeneratedRedemptionCode.available.count).to be > 0
     create_concurrent_calls(Code, :get_code, [category.id])
     expect
     ... so on ..
```

I have `self.use_transactional_fixtures = false` in my describe but seem like it's not working. My get_code method will raise a StandardError if no code found for that category and it just pop out every time I run my spec. Though my expect `expect(Code.count).to be > 0` is passed.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks